# Twine: How to create click link for number variable

Tags: twine-game-engine

The Problem lies at where i do the score editions, $numOrder is equivalent to a orderedArray of c1 c2 c3 but i can't seem to use them as hook for click. The error message says it expects a ?this or string. Can click hook be a number?

```
      (print: "$temp <br/>")
      <b>(print: "$c1   $c2   $c3")</b>
      (set: $numOrder to (sorted:...(a:$c1,$c2,$c3)))
      (if: $temp is $Bigger)
      [
        (click:$numOrder's 1st)[(set:$score to $score-0.5)]
        (click:$numOrder's 2nd)[(set:$score to $score-0.5)]
        (click:$numOrder's 3rd)[(set:$score to $score+1)]
      ]
      (elseif:$temp is $Smaller)
      [
        (click:$numOrder's 1st)[(set:$score to $score+1)]
        (click:$numOrder's 2nd)[(set:$score to $score-0.5)]
        (click:$numOrder's 3rd)[(set:$score to $score-0.5)]
      ]
      (else:)
      [
        (click:$numOrder's 1st)[(set:$score to $score-0.5)]
        (click:$numOrder's 2nd)[(set:$score to $score+1)]
        (click:$numOrder's 3rd)[(set:$score to $score-0.5)]
      ]
    ]
    (else:)
    [
    (print:"<br\><br\>Well that was easy!")
    (stop:)
    ]

]}
```

Comment: I think you might have used the wrong tag, 'twine' is for the Python Package Index upload tool. What are you using here?

Comment: @ECH This is [Twine the interactive story writing tool](https://twinery.org/).

Comment: @JJJ Ok, but the current tag 'twine' is incorrect in this instance. It is not going to get the people finding it who you would like to find it

Comment: @ECH Agreed, but I'm not the OP (and I can't think of a good name for a new tag to disambiguate.)